# "Gnome power management  is not configured properly" error when logging into GNOME session

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

When I log in to Ubuntu (GNOME), after I enter the password nothing appears. But a small 
message tells me that

> GNOME power management is not configured properly, and ask the Administrator to fix it.

Is there any way to reset the preferences? I have KDE and every thing works very good. But I want to run GNOME again...

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, this error occurs if you don't have enough disk space available.

Drop to TTY1 using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>.

Enter the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo reboot
```

The last command will reboot the system for you. Try logging in now.

---

If the above doesn't work, you might want to try chmodding /tmp to 0777

```
chmod 0777 /tmp
```

[(source)](http://www.geekdevs.com/2010/04/solved-unable-to-boot-due-to-gnome-power-manager-error/)